# ctags does not work for long file names

Tags: ctags

I used

```
ctags -e -R foo
```

to generate TAGS. But TAGS includes file names, as tags, like

```
foo/a/bar/d/vvv.cpp
```

The real file name should be

```
foo/abc/bar/ddd/vvv.cppp
```

So it cannot find the correct files.

Is it because my file name is too long?

Answer (score 0):

This is because I did

```
ctags -e -R ./foo/
```

It does not have the issue if I do

```
ctags -e -R foo/
```